# Is there way to access <slot /> data in script tag?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I used slot HTML element to print the passed data from parent component to child component. And I want to use the data in my methods inside script tag inside child component. Is there a way to access the slot data and assign it to an object in the data method?

My parent component

```
<template>
  <div class="footer">
      <app-footer>Contacts</app-footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

My child component

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
      <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your slot in an element, you can use the [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) tag to get a reference to the wrapper. Referencing slots directly is not supported, because it can be a single element, or multiple elements.

E.g.

```
<div class='wrap' ref='wrap'>
  <slot />
</div>
```

In js;

```
this.$refs.wrap // contains an HTMLElement
this.$refs.wrap.childNodes // contains (all) the element(s) in the wrap / slot
```

You can also use `this.$slots` and `this.$children` to get vue components you place in the slots.

Comment: I tried to see the slot value in console using `console.log(this.$refs.wrap)`, it shows an undefined value.

Comment: Whoops set the `slot` attribute on the wrap instead of `ref`. Example now fixed.

Comment: Well, this was very helpful. It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple bind that data on parent component and get it as a prop on child

```
<template>
  <div class="footer">
      <app-footer :data="data">Contacts</app-footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
      <slot />
  </div>
</template>

export default {
 props: {
  data: Object // <- here you receives parent data
 }
}
```